# The file size of jQuery

Tags: jquery, gzip

On jQuery's official website, they say the minified file size is 18k, but after downloading, I found that is 53.9K, do I have to do something to compress it after downloading?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The website states it's 18k minified and **gzipped**. So you need to setup your web server to compress JavaScript files to see that file size.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use less bandwidth both from your server, and to your visitors, you should let [Google host jQuery](http://code.google.com/intl/nb/apis/ajaxlibs/) for you. Reasons (from [encosia.com](http://encosia.com/2008/12/10/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/)):

- Decreased Latency
- Increased parallelism
- Better caching

Here is one way to do it. (The other way is with *google.load()*, see the link above):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Your code here
  });
</script>
```

Comment: From http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/ : The AJAX Libraries API is a content distribution network and loading architecture for the most popular, open source JavaScript libraries. By using the google.load() method, your application has high speed, globally available access to a growing list of the most popular, open source JavaScript libraries.