# How to get 19KB Minified version of jquery file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xhtml

Jquery.com shows Minified and Gzipped version as 19KB?

```
Production (19KB, Minified and Gzipped)   
Development (120KB, Uncompressed Code)
```

but when we click on download for Production version. it goes to this link

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/downloads/detail?name=jquery-1.3.2.min.js&downloadBtn=

and the file which is on this page it's size is 55.9 KB. Why jquery.com showing **Production (19KB, Minified and Gzipped)**

Comment: I found similar question like mine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494391/the-file-size-of-jquery

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The file's unzipped size is 55.9 kB. That is the result of the *minification*, which is a shortening of variable names, stripping of white space and the likes.

When you gzip it additionally, it will lose even more size. The gzipped file is downloaded by the browser and unzipped into the 55.9 kB large, minified version internally so it can be read by the JS interpreter.

You can zip files using [gzip](http://www.gzip.org) but usually, if the server is set up correctly, the server will automatically serve gzipped files if the browser signals it can handle them. In that case you don't have to do anything. You can see whether a file was transmitted gzipped using the "view size information" tab in the [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) for Firefox.

Comment: i'm using jquery on asp.net site how can i gzipped to compress

Comment: file is already unzipped http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js it's in .js format not in .zip format

Comment: u mean i can compress file to get in 19 KB size using gzip.org and it will work same like unzipped version

Comment: Yes but you won't need to. Make sure your server serves the content gzipped.

Comment: how can i check server is capable or not to server gzipped content? my site is asp.net based

Comment: It depends on your server, not site. Check the request headers using a proxy (like Charles) and see if the Accept-Encoding header contains gzip or deflate (which is a similar compression)

Comment: Jitendra: Check the last paragraph of my answer, with the Toolbar you can find out whether your server serves minified stuff or not.

Comment: I've checked my server info saying "Content-Encoding: gzip"

Comment: If you want to make sure your jquery is delivered zipped, I would still make sure using the WDT or Firebug. Content enconding could be on for certain filetypes only.

Comment: how can i check if i add jquery gzipped version to my asp.net website then my IIS server will serve as a gzipped or not ? I work in a company i can't edit anything in server. but how to know it will support or not. and if it's not possible to know or if my server doesn't support, what are other methods to compress jquery file to maximum possible level?

Comment: Web Developer Toolbar > Information > View Document Size

showing - jquery.js  22 KB (56 KB uncompressed)

Comment: it means if i add minified 55 kb version , my server will automatically gzipped

Comment: i just need to add minified version in header of my site. ok. but if i use goole link in place of my hosted juery file then my server will gzipped google version or not

Answer (score 10):

> How to get 19KB Minified version of
>   jquery file?

```
% wget http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js

% gzip jquery-1.3.2.min.js

% du -b jquery-1.3.2.min.js.gz

19716   jquery-1.3.2.min.js.gz
```

Answer (score 3):

Download this [JQuery minified](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/downloads/detail?name=jquery-1.3.2.min.js&downloadBtn=) version.  Then ensure that your webserver is gzipping output. You need to ensure [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html) is enabled and then place the following (similar) setting in your .htaccess file:

```
# compress all text & html:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/x-javascript application/javascript text/css .php

# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<Files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Files>
```

That will ensure your files are gzipped to the browser.  You can use the webdeveloper toolbar to check the sizes.

To do this in IIS then follow [this tutorial](http://www.smallworkarounds.net/2009/01/aspnet-iis-tricks-using-gzip.html)